# How to programmatically execute a ReccurringJob immediately?

Tags: hangfire

I have a number of Hangfire recurring jobs that are working well.

However, I need to add the facility to allow users to preempt the schedule and run a task immediately.

This is my startup:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<SendFilesJob>("SendFilesJob", j => j.Execute(), send_schedule);
```

I tell users when a job has run last and when it will run next, like so:

```
using (var connection = JobStorage.Current.GetConnection())
{
    foreach (var recurringJob in connection.GetRecurringJobs())
    {
        //report LastExecution, NextExecution, LastJobState
    }
}
```

This also shows when a job is currently processing via `LastJobState`, which is great.

However, when a user preempts to run the task immediately, I call it like so:

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue<SendFilesJob>(j => j.Execute());
```

This works, but it doesn't hook into the recurring job entry reporting; so users don't see a change in the `LastJobState` or `LastExecution` values.

Is there a way to access the `RecurringJob` itself and fire it so it updates those values?

Answer (score 6):

You can try to use `RecurringJob.Trigger("job-id");`